# Accessing command line args from Scala Play controller

Tags: scala, playframework, command-line-arguments

How do I access command line args from a Scala Play controller? (e.g. sbt “run firstArg secondArg thirdArg”

Normally you would be able to access these by accessing the array ‘args’ from the object that extends ‘App’. However with Play, the controllers are your entry point, not an object extending ‘App’.

I have already tried using ‘with App’ on the play controller and referencing ‘args’, this doesn’t work.

Comment: What are these args used for? What do they represent?

Comment: You might want to use standard Java system args `-Dkey=value` (send as `-J-Dkey=value` via sbt). Also keep in mind that in production your app won't be running via SBT, thus don't do something SBT specific.

Comment: These args are values that my program will use (e.g. a base url for a client that I'd like to supply).

I know this isn't a representation of how it would work in production. I'm just trying to access these arguments when running the program locally.

So sbt "run -J-Dkey=someValue"? How would I send a second argument? And how do I access these arguments from inside the Play controller?

Comment: sbt "run -J-DfirstKey=firstVal -J-DsecondKey=secondVal" is that correct?

Comment: Sounds like you should rather use the configuration file _application.conf_ for such needs.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I would rather use configuration file than args passed through the start/run command.

See more about the possibilities at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile